# GCP MQL: Rename a line in monitoring chart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I have a simple Google Cloud Monitoring Query Language to show the count of all requests to all containers in kubernetes from log-based metrics. The query is below.

```
k8s_container::logging.googleapis.com/user/service-api-gateway-prod-request-in-count | sum
```

The widget will look like below

[image]

I would like to rename the long label for the line chart to something shorter like "request count". How do I do it?

Comment: Is `service-api-gateway-prod-request-in-count` a custom metric? I can not find it in [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_k8s_container)

Comment: It's a "log-based metric" as mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

So the best I can do is to add a new column to the table and map the column.

In my example, I add `add [p: 'error count'] | map [p]` to the line, and become like this.

```
k8s_container::logging.googleapis.com/user/service-api-gateway-prod-request-in-count | sum | add [p: 'error count'] | map [p]
```

This works in my case.

#### References

- https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#map

Comment: This worked for me as well and appears to be the most straightforward way to rename the line with an arbitrary string. Please consider accepting your own answer as the solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using MQL(Monitoring Query Language), try the Advanced tab. Just for an example I will be using a metric name **mysite-container-exited**, you can name it whatever you want.

- Select your resource type and metric that you created in log-based metric.
- Select No preprocessing step.
- Select alignment function as **SUM**.
  Now the widget will just show the name that you entered in the log-based metric details tab.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` is actually a shortcut to `group_by` table operation with `sum` aggregator. Using the complete form of `group_by` allow you to control the output value column name.

```
k8s_container::logging.googleapis.com/user/service-api-gateway-prod-request-in-count
| group_by [], [request_count: sum(val())]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try renaming the value column with `| value [request_count: val()]`.

[Reference entry for the value operator](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#value-tabop)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).